# Multi-platform multi-module builds with Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, swt

I have a large project which uses SWT on several different platforms like windows (32 and 64 bits), linux-gtk (32 and 64 bits) etc. The project has several modules in a simple structure:

```
project-parent
 +- core
 +- swt-bridge (uses SWT)
 +- module1 (uses swt-bridge module)
 +- module2
 +- ...
 +- module17 (uses swt-bridge module)
```

I would like to be able to run my code from Eclipse on all the supported platforms. E.g. if I look at the `swt-bridge` module on a 32-bit Windows machine, it should have the 32-bit Windows SWT dependencies, and also have the required DLLs extracted to some directory which I can then add to `java.library.path`.

I can specify different dependencies by defining profiles activated by `os.family` and `os.arch`.

```
 <profile>
  <id>macos</id>
  <activation>
   <os>
    <family>macosx</family>
    <arch>x86</arch>
   </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
   <swt.native.groupId>org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx</swt.native.groupId>
   <swt.native.artifactId>x86</swt.native.artifactId>
   <swt.native.version>3.5.1</swt.native.version>
  </properties>
 </profile>
```

I can also use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to extract any DLLs, .so files from the SWT JAR to `target/swtlib`, and use them from Eclipse.

This works fine if I put the profiles in the `swt-bridge` module. But this way I cannot see the properties set by the active profile from other projects, so e.g. I cannot use the dependency plugin with these properties (which I would like to).

I thought I could solve this by moving the profiles to the parent POM, and indeed, if I build the whole product, it works. But this way I cannot just build one module, because Maven will complain about missing properties.

I'm pretty sure many people face this problem, so there must be a way to handle this properly in Maven. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: Am I right assuming that you have a real maven projects inheritance (i.e. subproject pom contains <parent> element with corresponding parent project coordinates) and says that single child module can't be built because of missing properties?

Comment: Yes, there are the proper pointers to <parent>. Does anything say that I'm not allowed to build a module on its own this way?

Comment: Well, Maven documentation says the following: 'When a project specifies a parent, it inherits the information in the parent project's POM. It can then override and add to the values specified in this parent POM'. I.e. your child project is assumed to see parent project properties. I just checked that if the parent project defines an activated profile and it is activated, maven build for child project sees correct properties from it.

Comment: I'll downvote this question, and would vote up as soon as you accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Project inheritance should work here: `properties` are inherited if you place them in the parent pom **and** if the profile is activated. Please note that I said *activated* and not *active* for the current project (see [MNG-3228](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3228) for the difference between both terms).

I've setup a simple multi-modules build demonstrating properties inheritance from a profile in the parent pom with maven 2.2.1. The project has the following structure:

```
.
|-- my-module
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   `-- java
|       `-- test
|           `-- java
`-- pom.xml
```

The parent pom.xml is defined as follow (adapted to my platform):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>my-module</module>
  </modules>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>linux-x86</id>
      <properties>
        <someVar>some value</someVar>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <name>Linux</name>
          <arch>i386</arch>
        </os>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And this is the pom of the module:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <echo message="${someVar}"/>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

If I run Maven from the parent:

```
$ mvn help:active-profiles compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'help'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [help:active-profiles] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [help:active-profiles {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

 - linux-x86 (source: pom)



Active Profiles for Project 'com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT': 

There are no active profiles.



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/my-app/my-module/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] some value
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [0.003s]
[INFO] Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [1.256s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 22 18:08:16 CEST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/80M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if I run maven from the module:

```
$ cd my-module
$ mvn help:active-profiles compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'help'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [help:active-profiles] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [help:active-profiles {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT': 

There are no active profiles.



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.app:my-module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/my-app/my-module/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] some value
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 22 18:09:38 CEST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/79M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the profile is activated (but not active) and the property defined in the profile in the parent pom is inherited.